# Handling User Preferences/States in REST API

Tags: rest, session, restful-authentication

We're starting to migrate our Website to a REST Service based system and are in the process of developing the core right now.

In our current setup a user has one or more "accounts" assigned which define what data he can see on the website. Only one account can be active for a given user at any  time. Right now we store the selected account in the database and use it to filter all queries.

Now I'm not sure how to handle this properly in a REST environment. Possible solutions I found are:

- Sending the requested account with every request
- Storing the current account in the auth token. (We're using JWT for that)
- Having the current account stored on the server and calling a specific resource to change it

Each of these has its pros and cons for our setup. Currently we're using the 3rd approach in our Website. But what would be the correct way to handle such a thing in a REST environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea the design you are dealing with is fairly bad, and what you really want to do is remove the state completely out of this system.

For that reason the first option is by far superior:

> Sending the requested account with every request

If this is simply an id, there's a very simple way to do this, just prefix all your (relevant) routes / uris with this account id. For example:

```
http://api.example.org/accounts/{id}/...
```

This way the 'state' is maintained by virtue of which url you are accessing, and the server can be unaware of the state.